# Multivariate Encoder-Decoder Model approaches value

Tags: keras, time-series, data-science, lstm, encoder-decoder

I am creating my first multivariate multistep encoder-decoder LSTM to forecast revenues.

As you can see, the values move towards a value and then stop at that value. The aim is to create a forecast for a longer period, but there is no deviation at all from this standard value after the first week.
What is wrong and what can I do? To me it doesn't look like it is working at all.

### code:

```
    class ModelTrainer:
        def __init__(self, prediction_length=30, offset=1):
            self.prediction_length = prediction_length
            self.offset = offset
            self._setup_values()
            self.use_scaling = True
            self.__prepare_data()
    
        def _setup_values(self):
            # Model configuration
            self.additional_metrics = ['accuracy']
            self.embedding_output_dims = 15
            self.max_sequence_length = 300
            self.num_distinct_words = 5000
            self.verbosity_mode = 1
    
            # DATA
            self.WINDOW_LENGTH = 70  # ! SHOULD BE ADJUSTED TO THE AMOUNT OF FORECASTING DAYS
            self.SAMPLING_RATE = 1
            self.BATCH_SIZE = 128
    
            # MODEL
            self.DROPOUT = 0.3
            self.NODES_PER_LAYER = 256
            self.NUMBER_OF_LAYERS = 3
    
            # TRAINING
            self.LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
            self.OPTIMIZER = Adam(learning_rate=self.LEARNING_RATE)
            self.VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.20
            self.NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS = 10
            self.TEST_SIZE = 0.1
            self.RANDOM_STATE = 123
            self.LOSS_FUNCTION = MeanSquaredError()
    
        def __import_data(self):
            self.series = DataOrganizer().df
    
        def __prepare_data(self):
            self.__import_data()
            self.scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
            data_scaled = self.scaler.fit_transform(self.series)
            self.features, self.target = self._create_feature_target_values_window(
                data_scaled)
    
        def _create_feature_target_values_window(self, data):
            self.number_of_output_columns = 4
            feature_data = data
            target_data = data[:, :self.number_of_output_columns]
            features, target = list(), list()
            in_start = 0
            for _ in range(len(data)):
                in_end = in_start + self.WINDOW_LENGTH
                out_end = in_end + self.prediction_length
                if out_end <= len(data):
                    features.append(feature_data[in_start:in_end, :])
                    target.append(
                        target_data[in_end:out_end, 0:self.number_of_output_columns])
                in_start += 1
            return np.array(features), np.array(target)
    
        def __create_LSTM_model(self):
            num_feature_columns = self.features.shape[2]
            num_output_columns = self.target.shape[2]
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(LSTM(self.NODES_PER_LAYER, input_shape=(
                self.WINDOW_LENGTH, num_feature_columns)))
            model.add(Dropout(self.DROPOUT))
            model.add(RepeatVector(self.prediction_length))
            model.add(LSTM(self.NODES_PER_LAYER, return_sequences=True))
            model.add(Dropout(self.DROPOUT))
            model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(self.NODES_PER_LAYER)))
            model.add(Dropout(self.DROPOUT))
            model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(num_output_columns)))
            model.summary()
            return model
    
        def train_model(self, callbacks=[]):
            model = self.__create_LSTM_model()
            model.compile(loss=self.LOSS_FUNCTION,
                          optimizer=self.OPTIMIZER,
                          metrics=['accuracy', MeanAbsoluteError()]
                          )
            model.fit(
                x=self.features,
                y=self.target,
                epochs=self.NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS,
                validation_split=self.TEST_SIZE,
                shuffle=False,
                callbacks=callbacks
            )
            self.model = model
    
        def create_forecast(self):
            prediction = self.model.predict(self.features[-1:])
            # prediction = self.model.predict(self.features[-30:-29]) # Show forecast from a month old
            test_X = self.features.copy()
            test_X = test_X[:self.prediction_length,
                            :1, self.number_of_output_columns:]
            test_X = test_X.reshape(
                self.prediction_length, self.series.shape[1] - self.number_of_output_columns)
            prediction = prediction.reshape(self.prediction_length,
                                            self.number_of_output_columns)
            inv_yhat = np.concatenate((prediction, test_X), axis=1)
            inv_yhat = self.scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
            prediction_df = pd.DataFrame(
                inv_yhat, columns=self.scaler.feature_names_in_)
            first_date = self.series.last_valid_index() + timedelta(days=1)
            last_date = first_date + timedelta(days=self.prediction_length-1)
            days = pd.date_range(first_date, last_date, freq='D')
            prediction_df.set_index(days, inplace=True)
            prediction_df = prediction_df[self.series.columns[0:4]]
```

### Actual

[image: actual]

### Forecast:

(I know the x-axis description is incorrect. Don't worry about it)
[image: forecast]

Comment: It looks like your model only predicts the mean value (after a while). In general can LSTMs be difficult to train. I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129288/lstm-predicting-the-same-constant-values-after-a-while) is related and might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I will check it out